# Audio/Video codecs for Android platform

Tags: android, codec, video-codecs

I'm looking for, either open-source or commercially available, Audio and Videl encoder & decoder for Android for an application I want to write for Android. For audio, I want to be able to both encode-decode the AMR/AD-PCM/AAC formats and for Video H.263/H.264 & MPEG4 formats.

I can see from Android documentation that encoding & decoding AMR-NB audio format is provided by the Android platform and for Video H.263 is provided. But, for rest of the codecs (both Audio & Video) that I've listed, decoder is there but not encoder (If I got it right).

Can anyone please help me in providing me with the pointers/suggestions for how/where can I find these codecs that are optimized/suitable for Android?

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone please help me in providing
>   me with the pointers/suggestions for
>   how/where can I find these codecs that
>   are optimized/suitable for Android?

Contact PacketVideo (authors of the OpenCORE multimedia engine), and be prepared to write a check for a very large sum of money.

Or, use the [Native Development Kit (NDK)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) and transcode the video from a supported format to the one you want.

Or, use a server to transcode the video from a supported format to the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think option 3 would be a quicker one to deploy for me though finding such a server might be tricky job. But I guess I'm still more inclined to have such a function in my app.  
I wanted to avoid option 2 that you'd suggested as I expect it to take much longer time.  
But thanx a ton for these suggestions. At least there is one way around that I know now.